# Do I need to create multiple functions for multiple actions or can they all be housed in the same function?

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, show-hide

I'm working on a script to simulate a page change in a Questionnaire I'm building.  I figured maybe I could use a bunch of "if" statements to house all the logic but it's not working right, before I go and create separate functions I'd like to know if it's possible to put them all in one single function.

So far this is the script

```
function pageChange(){
        var chng1 = document.getElementById("p1next");
        var chng2a = document.getElementById("p2back");
        var chng2b = document.getElementById("p2next");
        var chng3a = document.getElementById("p3back");
        var chng3b = document.getElementById("p3next");
        var pg1 = document.getElementById("page01");
        var pg2 = document.getElementById("page02");
        var pg3 = document.getElementById("page03");

        if (chng1.click){
            pg1.style.display="none";
            pg2.style.display="block";
            }
        if (chng2a.click){
            pg1.style.display="block";
            pg2.style.display="none";
            }
```

the "p1next, p2back, p2next etc." are IDs I gave the buttons on the pages, which I have in DIVs that I respectively named "page01, page02, page03 etc."

Without the 2nd if statement the script works exactly how I want it, it changes the display for "page01" to none and the div for "page02" to block. When I add the second if statement it doesn't work.

The reason I want to do it like this rather than making actual pages is because I don't want the data to get lost when they load another page.  Am I on the right track or do I need to create a new function for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly on the right track, you should use `onclick` events, instead of `if (x.click)` like this:

```
var chng1 = document.getElementById("p1next");
var pg1 = document.getElementById("page01");
var pg2 = document.getElementById("page02");

// Events
chng1.onclick = function(){
    pg1.style.display="none";
    pg2.style.display="block";
};
```

This will save your function until the element is clicked and then execute that function. In your case, it is executed on page load, and at that moment the user is not clicking anything.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this:

HTML:

`<div class="page" data-pg="1">...</div>`
`<div class="page" data-pg="2">...</div>`
`<div class="page" data-pg="3">...</div>`
`<input id="btnPrev" type="button" value="Prev" />`
`<input id="btnNext" type="button" value="Next" />`

jQuery:

`var pageNum = 1;`

`$(document).ready(function () {`
    `$("#btnPrev").on("click", function () { ChangePage(-1); });`
    `$("#btnNext").on("click", function () { ChangePage(1); });`

`ChangePage(0);`
`});`

`function ChangePage(p) {`
    `$(".page").hide();`
    `pageNum += p;`
    `$(".page[data-pg='" + p + "']").show();`

`$("#btnPrev").removeAttr("disabled");`
    `$("#btnNext").removeAttr("disabled");`

`if (pageNum === 1) $("#btnPrev").attr("disabled", "disabled");`
    `if (pageNum === $(".page").length) $("#btnNext").attr("disabled", "disabled");`
`}`

That way you can easily grow your number of pages without changing the script. My apologies by the way for doing this in jQuery.

---

Update:

Have a lot of time on my hands today and have not coded for while using vanilla Javascript. Here's the version of the code using plain js: https://jsfiddle.net/hhnbz9p2/

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what any of that means or how to use it lol.  in the html you have the attribute "data-pg=", what exactly is that?

Comment: It's a custom attribute. It does not have any effect on the element. It just stores data. So what the script basically does is: 1) hide all the pages (divs with the class "page") first, 2) updates the value of current page number, 3) displays the page that has the value of the current page number.

Comment: By doing this, the script need not be changed as you add pages. Just add a div and set the appropriate data-pg (can be named anything really as this is a custom attribute) value. Hope you could check out jQuery. Might help you a lot. Good day!

Comment: just to be clear, the "data-pg" doesn't mean anything in html, but is just something that you can tell the JQuery to look for and use in whatever way you code the JQuery to use it?